# Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Tags: c#, this

```
public static void Main()
{
    Stream s1 = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication1.sudhir.jpg");
    Stream s2 = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication1.sunil.jpg");
    Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(s1);
    Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap(s2);

    if (img1.Size != img2.Size)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Images are of different sizes");
        return;
    }

    float diff = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < img1.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < img1.Width; x++)
        {
            diff += (float)Math.Abs(img1.GetPixel(x, y).R - img2.GetPixel(x, y).R) / 255;
            diff += (float)Math.Abs(img1.GetPixel(x, y).G - img2.GetPixel(x, y).G) / 255;
            diff += (float)Math.Abs(img1.GetPixel(x, y).B - img2.GetPixel(x, y).B) / 255;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("diff: {0} %", 100 * diff / (img1.Width * img1.Height * 3));
```

Here I'm trying to match the two images and finding their difference but I'm getting this error

> Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer.

What's wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` method is static, so you cannot call `this.`
Instead you could write:

```
 Stream s1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication1.sudhir.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2):

the keyword this is valid only in cases you work with objects (i mean insances). When you use static method, it means you don't deal with a specific object but with a class and because of that "this" doesn't point on anything.

Answer (score 2):

"this" is an invisible parameter that points to the current instance of a class. Since you declared a method as static, there's no way you can access to it. This is not only in C#. C++ also has "this".

Answer (score 1):

'this' is meaningful only in the context of an object, and can not be used in static code. If you need to refer to 'this' when setting the starting value of a field, set that value in the constructor.

The error message will have told you which line of which file is causing the problem. I don't think it's any of the lines you've shown us.